# Update-Manager stuck while installing package to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, update-manager

Update-Manager appears to be stuck.

last package installed appears to be an apache module, but I didn't realize I had installed apache (possible a prerequisite for another package installed?).

I left it for about an hour hoping that it would progress but the bar never moved and last installed package hasn't changed. It was sitting at about 75% complete in the entire upgrade/package install process before I had to head out (won't be home for a few hours, but this has been bothering me all day).

Has anyone experienced this? Is there a way to recover? A way to stop the current process and force it to continue? My fear is that if I force a reboot, that it won't boot properly or there will be much in the way of broken packages.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem and realized after waiting 3 hours that it was "frozen" because there was a hidden window that was asking me to confirm that I wanted to remove the obsolete packages that dist-packages found.  If you're experiencing this, click on the "Distribution Upgrade" Menu icon to check for hidden windows.

Answer (score 0):

From the commandline run the following to clear this up:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you get errors after the last command update your question with the error output.  You may have to repeat the three commands to get it all synced.

Comment: I will try this tonight when I get home. Didn't think it would be so simple. I tried this morning  with "sudo apt-get update" when the issue occurred but the Update-Manager was still active, and it couldn't get a lock. Hopefully this will fix it up (assuming it hasn't magically recovered on its own over the past 9 hours lol)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about not getting back on this. Been otherwise tied up. 
Rebooting did work, and over the next few days updates were pouring in. Seems stable.

Running into an issue with setting this with a static IP - but this is a query in another thread.